# Размер кнопок в телеграм боте на pytelegrambotapi (telebot)

Tags: python, telebot

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Кнопка ОДИН")
btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Кнопка ДВА")
btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Кнопка ТРИ")
markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
```

В результате я имею каждую кнопку в отдельной строке.
Как сделать так, что бы первая кнопка была во всю ширину на первой строке, а две других кнопки во второй?

Хочу, что бы было вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно получиться то, что вы хотите:

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Кнопка ОДИН")
btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Кнопка ДВА")
btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Кнопка ТРИ")
markup.add(btn1).row(btn2, btn3)
```